# Concurrent access to the same .pyc

Tags: python, multithreading, interpreter, gil

I'm currently working on a C# application which should be able to launch multiple Python interpreters.

I've read several articles on the subject such as :

- http://www.awasu.com/weblog/embedding-python/threads/
- http://jessenoller.com/blog/2009/02/01/python-threads-and-the-global-interpreter-lock
- [Multiple independent embedded Python Interpreters on multiple operating system threads invoked from C/C++ program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968317/multiple-independent-embedded-python-interpreters-on-multiple-operating-system-t)

I'm experiencing a problem where sometimes the *.pyc files of the imported libraries are no more accessible because it seems that they have been corrupted.

My question is :
Is it possible that launching multiple interpreter, let's say 50 maximum can cause this kind of behaviour?

Regards

Edit: I've changed the title, I'm having hard times to reproduce the probleme

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer there 
Here is the answer:

- [Running a python script concurrently over the network. Is this OK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995467/running-a-python-script-concurrently-over-the-network-is-this-ok)

python -B solved it